# Ember upgrade 1.7 to 1.13.* fails with buildRenderNodes is not a function

Tags: grails, ember.js

I was using ember as a part of my grails application, All libs were provided by a ember grails plugin 1.7. As I would eventually like to move to newer version I have tried both to replace ember and ember-data with newer files versions as well as to add references to hosted files, but I would always get during run:

```
template.buildRenderNodes is not a function
```

Comment: You will have an easier time if you upgrade incrementally, ie 1.7 to 1.8, 1.8 to 1.9 etc. that way you can work your way through the deprecation notices.

Comment: @Christopher well it is not a deprecation notice. the app stopped loading

Comment: Yes, but you are not seeing a lot of the deprecation notices, because a deprecation notice for version 1.8 wouldn't show up in version 1.13—the code would have long since been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess from that error message would be you are still referencing handlebars rather than htmlbars which Ember now uses. You now need `ember-template-compiler.js`, see http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release.

As Christopher mentions, you will probably feel less pain by going up a version at a time and also moving to Ember CLI if you haven't already